# Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying to draw charges and electric field vector on VScode,but it always pop out error message

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Define charges location and magnitude
\def\chargeA{(0,0)}
\def\chargeB{(4,0)}
\def\chargeASize{0.3}
\def\chargeBSize{0.3}

% draw charges
\draw (\chargeA) circle (\chargeASize) node[above] {$+q$} ;
                       
\draw (\chargeB) circle (\chargeBSize) node[above] {$-q$} ;

% draw electric field vector
\draw [->, thick] (\chargeA) -- node[above] {$\vec{E}$} (\chargeB) ;
                                

\draw [->, thick] (\chargeB) -- node[below] {$\vec{E}$} (\chargeA) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

like this

```
Package tikz: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.
```

but i already put semicolon on the end of line.

Comment: Your first two macros have another set of () in them, remove them.

Comment: Why are you using macros to store coordinates? Use coordinates: `\coordinate (chargeA) at (0,0);` etc and then use `\draw[...] (chargeA) .... `

Comment: thx guys it works! after remove () , and thx suggest me use `\coordinate` . The code looks more pretty

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram

[image]

can be drawn with following MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4cm,
            > = Straight Barb,
charge/.style = {circle, draw, fill=white, 
                 inner sep=0pt, minimum size = 3mm,
                 label=#1, node contents={}},
                        ]
% Define charges location 
\node (A) [charge=$+q$];
\node (B) [charge=$-q$, right=of A];
%
% field
\draw[<->]   (A) to ["$\vec{E}$", "$\vec{E}$" '] (B);% 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or you may liked the following style of diagram:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4cm,
            > = Straight Barb,
    bend angle= 15,
charge/.style = {circle, draw, fill=white, 
                 inner sep=0pt, minimum size = 3mm,
                 label=#1, node contents={}},
every edge/.append style = {draw, ->}
                        ]
% Define charges location 
\node (A) [charge=$+q$];
\node (B) [charge=$-q$, right=of A];
%
% field
\draw   (A) edge [bend left, "$\vec{E}$"] (B)
        (B) edge [bend left, "$\vec{E}$"] (A); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the image, the `+q` and `-q` don't look like math.  Do those expressions need to be quoted?  (just a guess; not tested.)

Comment: `charge/.style={…, label=$#1$}` and then `charge=$…$` leads to non-math output as you can see in your pictures. Remove one set of `$`s. Also, this isn't safe if the charge contains `,` or`=`. Better use `label={$#1$}`. Though, if you're already loading the `quotes` library, a syntax like `charge, "$-q$"` or even `charge, "-q"` with the right label setup might be better.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, you are right. Corrected now.